# Magento2 - Category Filter not working with Amasty Layered Navigation after Magento2 Migration (2.2)

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter, data-migration

Category Filter not working with Amasty Layered Navigation after Magento2 Migration (2.2). Others attributes filter working fine except category.

Answer (score 2):

Root category anchor attribute need to be set "Yes". You can do this from the Admin => CATALOG => Catagories => Display Setting and set Anchor to Yes.